# Using a variable from a function outside the function

Tags: python, function, text, tkinter, return

Im writing this basic Tk program that can open text documents but i can seem to get it to work

Here is my code:

```
from Tkinter import *
from tkFileDialog import askopenfilename
def openfile():
   filename = askopenfilename(parent=root)
   f = open(filename)
   x = f.read()
   return x


root = Tk()
menubar = Menu(root)
filemenu = Menu(menubar, tearoff=0)
filemenu.add_command(label="Open", command=openfile)
filemenu.add_separator()
filemenu.add_command(label="Exit", command=root.quit)
menubar.add_cascade(label="File", menu=filemenu)


text = Text(root)
text.insert(INSERT,(x))

text.pack()

root.config(menu=menubar)
root.mainloop()
```

im trying to input `x` into my tk window but its saying its not defined even though i returned x

why isnt this working im sure its something easy but i cant figure it out!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So you have two related problems here.

1. You're trying to use `x` even though you haven't defined it yet
2. Returning anything from `openfile` won't work in this situation since you can't set it as another variable (like `x`)

What you probably want to do is read the file and insert it in the `Text` widget all in the same function call. Try something like this,

```
from Tkinter import *
from tkFileDialog import askopenfilename

def openfile():
    filename = askopenfilename(parent=root)
    f = open(filename)
    x = f.read()
    text.insert(INSERT,(x,))

root = Tk()
menubar = Menu(root)
filemenu = Menu(menubar, tearoff=0)
filemenu.add_command(label="Open", command=openfile)
filemenu.add_separator()
filemenu.add_command(label="Exit", command=root.quit)
menubar.add_cascade(label="File", menu=filemenu)

text = Text(root)
text.pack()

root.config(menu=menubar)
root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 1):

When you return a value from a function, you need to assign it to a variable like so (**pseudocode**):

```
myVariable = openfile()
```

And then you can use this variable in your arguments as:

```
text.insert(INSERT, (myVariable))
```

Variable x is defined within the function so its out of scope.

Comment: when i do it this way when i run the GUI it just opens up the file dialog instead of opening the GUI then waiting for the user to click Open

Comment: @ChristianCareaga Don't have python on this computer or I'd check the code for you. Sorry.